# Can we reach an EC2 instance in private subnet through a transit gateway from internet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, cloud

I'm trying to setup AWS transit gateway following this - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/creating-a-single-internet-exit-point-from-multiple-vpcs-using-aws-transit-gateway/

I'm able to reach internet from private subnet via transit gateway.  But, is it possible to reach the instance in private subnet from internet?

Answer (score 0):

The question basically boils down to: is it possible to connect to an instance in a private subnet behind a NAT gateway?

The answer is no, because NAT gateways managed by AWS don't accept traffic initiated from the internet.

Comment: Even private instances behind NAT Gateway are accessible via internet facing load balancers.  I'm trying to find if there could be cases like this via transit gateway.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the networking account that hosts the transit gateway, place a load balancer in the public VPC of that account.
2. Create a target group for the load balancer and add the explicit IP address of the instance you want to reach in another account/VPC connected to the same transit gateway.
3. Ensure the security group of the instance allows the incoming traffic from the LB.
4. Ensure the security group of the LB allows incoming traffic from the internet.

Your LB will accept connections on its public IP address. As there is only one target group with one target, the request gets forwarded to the given private IP address. From thereon, the regular TGW routing takes over, and just delivers the request to your private instance.